# Does iOS keeps view instances?

Tags: ios, uikit

Assuming we're in a view controller:

```
var btn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
self.view.addSubview(btn)
```

Since the `btn` instance is of the built-in UIButton class, does iOS keep my `btn` instance alive? Or does iOS keeps the button I created in another (optimized) way, not keeping the actual `btn` instance I created?

In other word, does iOS keep internally the UI hierarchy with the same view objects we create?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [`addSubview` retains the view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622616-addsubview#):

> This method establishes a strong reference to `view` and sets its next responder to the receiver, which is its new superview.

This has nothing to do with the view controller. As long as the superview exists, it will continue to maintain a strong reference to all its subviews.

Comment: Thanks! I thought iOS does some optimization in the case you're creating an object of a built-in class...

Comment: No, nothing like that. It's just standard reference counting.

Comment: I now wonder why does SwiftUI uses structs then... Under the hood, it still creates the UIKit object. I initially thought iOS does some optimization when you're instantiating built-in classes (like UIButton in my example) but since it doesn't, then how does struct helps?

Comment: A SwiftUI View is a description of the view hierarchy. It's just data, and thus a value type. It's does not directly represent the actual on-screen view, like a UIView does. Modifying a SwiftUI view means completely replacing the entire hierarchy with a new value, which is then compared to the old value to generate animations, transitions, and other changes in the underlying reference types.